Recursive nested string formatting
I want to take something like the following:
print('{test_{test2}}'.format(test2='test2', test_test2='test3'))

and produce:
test3

But I get the error:
ValueError: unexpected '{' in field name

How can I do this?

have you tried a "nested" second format since your first call produces a new format template?

see also How do I escape curly-brace ({}) characters characters in a string while using .format?

You should nest your formats like so:
print('{{test_{test2}}}'.format(test2='test2').format(test_test2='test3'))


Thanks. This works. Do you know of any way to do this with a single function call?

You can build a function to do it, but nothing builtin. The function can also try escaping all of the squiggly brackets except the innermost using regex. It won't work with other innocent brackets that don't designate a placeholder
